# How to hide api in class element on fetch foto from Google api places

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, google-api, google-places-api, capacitor

IONIC CAPACITOR AND REACT FOR NATIVE AND WEB APPS

When I m fetching photo data from google api with that code below. It works good but when i inspect on website i can see on photo src my APIKEY how can i solve that or what i should do ?

```
const fetchPhoto = async () => {
    if (photoName) {
      try {
        const maxHeightPx = 500;
        const maxWidthPx = 500;

        const url = `https://places.googleapis.com/v1/${photoName}/media?key=${GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}&maxHeightPx=${maxHeightPx}&maxWidthPx=${maxWidthPx}`;
        const response = await CapacitorHttp.post({ url });
        setPhoto(response.url);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setPhoto(images.thumbnail);
        setLoading(false);
        console.error("Error while fetching photo:", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

I dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

1. You should NOT be calling the api in your code like that.
2. Use [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) setup provided by google!

Comment: Note: the JavaScript class described in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos will work only with the Places API described at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos - which is the one that has been around for over a decade. However, the places.googleapis.com URL above would be the new Places API described at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-photos - and for this one there is no JavaScript setup, so indeed OP should probably use the JavaScript class that is available.

Comment: I did just like here -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-photos?hl=pl. I just want to fetch image and show it in IMG element. Img informations from nearby search is array Photos element

Answer (score 0):

*Okey guys. I solved that problem. I just need to change POST method to GET method.
Then I got good results.*